# Insert Frame to middle of Video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, video-processing, xuggler

I have a case where I need to insert a frame (or many frames) to the middle of a video.  I looked at doing ffmpeg cutting, inserting, and then concatenation but unfortunately I have a lot of cuts and the "stitch back" has a lot of choppiness.  My thought was that I could leave the video "whole" and then insert frames as the exact spot(s) that I need to do that.  This way I would solve the choppiness problem.

I am currently using ffmpeg and don't really see any way to accomplish this task with that tool.  Google doesn't seem to be providing much help either.

Has anyone done this before?  What did you do to insert frames at specific spots.

As an FYI - I am doing my processing in Java, using FFMPEG, and my video files are mp4 (although I could convert).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wondering if you found a solution to your problem?  I would like to do the same.

Comment: I need the same solution! Do you have a solution?

Comment: Have you found any solution? Please let know if yes...